# Variable value changes after pushing in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I was testing this little peace of code:

```
<script>
  var newData = {}, graphs = []
  for(var j=0; j<2; j++){
    newData["name"] = 'value '+ j
    console.log(newData["name"]);
    graphs.push(newData);
    console.log(graphs);
  }
</script>
```

I've got the following output in the webconsole:

```
value 0 
Array [ Object ] 
value 1 
Array [ Object, Object ]
```

All Objects in the Arrays have the exact same Values:

```
name:"value 1"
```

I am really struggling with this because I don't change any values and the name is still changed in the same loop.

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: You are changing a property of one and the same object. You're never creating a second object anywhere, there's only one object which gets referred to multiple times.

Comment: I'd just add, for clarity, that before the 2nd iteration of the loop occurs, the array is [{name:"value 0"}]. In the 2nd iteration, it becomes [{name:"value 1"},{name:"value 1"}].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Putting an object into an array in javascript means you're putting a **reference** to that object in the array rather than the **value** of that object. In your example, you create a single object, `newData` and you change the name property on that object in your loop. That means that at the end of the loop you're left with a `newData` object with `{'name': 'value 2'}`

When you then take a look at `graphs[0]`, it will tell you that it contains a **reference** to newData which looks like `{'name': 'value 2'}`. The same holds for `graphs[1]`

you can solve this by making a new object each time in your array as such:

```
graphs = []
for(var j=0; j<2; j++){
  var newData = {}
  newData["name"] = 'value '+ j
  console.log(newData["name"]);
  graphs.push(newData);
  console.log(graphs);
}
```

Comment: Mrmrmrm.... The *value* of a variable holding an object *is* a reference to said object. You *are* putting a *value* into the array, it just so happens that that value is an indirection... /pedantic :o)

Comment: you're absolutely correct, i'll update my answer to reflect that

Comment: Perhaps it should be noted that any changes to `newData["name"]` **after** the for loop (i.e. `newData["name"] = 'object name';`) would change the last item and only the last item in the `graphs` array unless of course newData was reinitialized again beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Edit : You have to reinitialize the `newData` in the loop. Because, the object reference of `newData` is same and it overwrites the old value with new value everytime and hence only latest value can be seen.

Try,

```
<script>
    var graphs = [];
    for(var j=0; j<2; j++){
      var newData = {};
      newData["name"] = 'value '+ j
      console.log(newData["name"]);
      graphs.push(newData);
      console.log(graphs);
   }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to deceze for his answer!
I forgot that Js just calls by reference.
This code is working:

```
var graphs = []
  for(var j=0; j<2; j++){ 
    newData = {}
    newData["name"] = 'value '+ j
    console.log(newData["name"]);
    graphs.push(newData);
    console.log(graphs);
  }
```